# 'Cannot read properties of undefined' error when trying to print a JSON response in PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I have the following code:

```
$url = 'https://json-api-url-domain.com/matches?id=XX&division=YY&teams=[ZZ]';

$cURL = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json'
));

$result = curl_exec($cURL);
curl_close($cURL);

$json = json_decode($result, true);
var_dump($json);
```

But with that I'm getting:

```
array (size=2)
  'name' => string 'TypeError' (length=9)
  'message' => string 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')' (length=56)
```

I can visit the API URL directly in a web browser and see the JSON response.

I've also tested the API URL with https://reqbin.com/curl and can see the same response as if I visit it directly in a browser. That site also has the option to generate code, which is essentially what I already have in PHP.

If I choose to generate js/AJAX code instead of PHP and use something like this:

```
async function json() {
  const url = 'https://json-api-url-domain.com/matches?id=XX&division=YY&teams=[ZZ]';

  const response = await fetch(url);

  const text = await response.text();

  console.log(text);
}

json();
```

I get the correct response printed in the console. :?

So I really don't understand what's going on.

Comment: looks like an error in the json generating script, not yours. Try var_dumping $json to see what that script produces.

Comment: @Roemer I'm already doing that in the last line of the first block of code. The output is the second block.

Comment: my bad I meant var_dumping `$result`

Comment: I get the same message but as a string rather than an array.

Comment: Then the scripot AJAX is calling has an error, not this script. Look at the script that should actually produce the JSON, it clearly doesn''t work but gives an error message. (So `https://json-api-url`. If you don't have access to that script (third party), you probably need parameters in your api call. Consult the third party's documentation.

Comment: The thing is though, I can visit the API URL directly in a web browser and see the JSON response.

Comment: Also, there is no documentation (that I'm aware of). It's for a new app that records sporting scores, tables etc. The organisation is moving away from what they've been using for some time and that our club has been able to scrape data from to populate pages on our own site. The old system is not being updated with data anymore, so I'm try to rework what we have in place to use the new data origin.

Comment: We cannot continue this "chat" (StackOverflow prohibits it). If you don't know the requirements, it becomes difficult. I'd say by the error they need a parameter, do you use ? in the URL? IF yes, supply the GET parameters to the call. Add the info about the browser to the question, it will be essential for people who know curl better than me. Good luck.

Comment: 1) Why are you setting a content-type request header for a GET request with no body? 2) Your URL is malformed. There should be a `/` between the domain name and any path or query parameter parts

Comment: #1 – sorry, I don't understand the question. #2 – I don't want to post the actual URL I'm accessing publicly so that's just an example but the parts are mostly the same. I've just edited it again.

Comment: 1) You have `'Content-Type: application/json'` in your request headers. Why? Your request has no request body so has no need to describe the format of the body content

Comment: I copied the code from another post as a starting point but even if I take it out, I still get the same result.

Comment: Often a `User-Agent` request header is one of the minimum requirements, that sites try to use to protect against requests by "bots".

Comment: @CBroe do you want to add that as an answer? It's solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often a `User-Agent` request header is one of the minimum requirements, that sites try to use to protect against requests by "bots".

When you make a client-side request using fetch, then your browser will likely add its usual User-Agent, so that's why that one worked; when you make the request using a tool like cURL, you will have to add one yourself in these kind of situations.